# ASP.NET token error reset password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, forgot-password, reset-password

I just add the "forgot password" part of MVC 5 in my project and i can't change my password after receiving the email.

The error:In the App => [Image of error in the app](http://hpics.li/c57b894)

In Visual Studio => [Image of error visual studio](http://hpics.li/f2092ea)

The code where the error come from:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        var code = model.Code.Replace(" ","+");
        **var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);**
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View();
    }
```

I tried many things find on stackoverflow and other but it didn't worked.

If you got any idea why i got this error :)

I use the basic template that is proposed at the creation of a ASP.NET web app in visual studio.
I can upload all code files you want, just ask what you need to help me and i'll upload it within 2minutes !

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you at least included the error you're seeing, along with any relevant code from the area that produces the error.

Comment: I've edited the initial post to show you the error i get @JamesThorpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem,

My callbackUrl had format with the token special characters and upperCase

First in the ForgotPasswordViewModel, i generated my URL manually, then i encode it right

```
            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            code = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
            string datcode = code;
            //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            var datUrl = "http://localhost:62989/Account/Resetpassword?" + user.Id + "&Code=" + code;
```

For the upperCase problem, i had forgot the ToTitleCase method when assigning the callbackurl to my emai message so i removed it.

```
            message = message.Replace("@ViewBag.Name", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(usernom));
            message = message.Replace("@ViewBag.CallBackUrl", datUrl);
            await MessageServices.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, emailSubject, message);
```

Second, i the ResetPasswordViewModel, i decode the token with

```
var code = WebUtility.UrlDecode(model.Code);
```

And replace the blank space by the original +,

```
code = code.Replace(' ', '+');
```

Finally it's working great in the ResetPasswordAsync function !

```
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, code, model.Password);
```

Thanks @Ravi for the help

Answer (score 1):

My issue was very similar but it happened to be my routing engine converting all URLs to lowercase (for SEO, etc).  I needed to make sure query string parameters allowed mixed case.  Base64 uses mixed case.

I added the `NoLowercaseQueryString` attribute to each of my controller methods.  This is specific to the [MVC Boilerplate project](http://rehansaeed.com/canonical-urls-for-asp-net-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using default template you might be using below code to generate callbackUrl

```
string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

You need to url encode the `code` (token) before sending it to email i.e. change it to `code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code)`

You don't need this line `var code = model.Code.Replace(" ","+");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried you solution by adding "code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);" but i continue to get the invalid token error message :/

Comment: Check the value of `code` before sending email and see if you are  receiving the same `code`. Due to encoding sometimes value changes slightly for special characters like + =.

Comment: I figured out hte problem with the '+' in the string being removed with a blank space and my upperCase being replaced by lowerCase, thanks a lot for the help @Ravi :)

Comment: @ClémentSébillet - Great please add your solution as answer and accept it.